# Warning1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I am reading and writing rasters using gdal and keep running into the error:

`Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.`

I have already processed dozens of images of the same type without issue (2012 - 2018). Unfortunately there is something going wrong with how the rasters are being written in my 2005-2010 data and I am not sure how I would remedy this.

The images are NAIP imagery downloaded from Earth Explorer. The first photo is the 2010 image that has a clear break in the left quarter of the image compared to the 2018, 2014 data (2nd, 3rd images).

I attached my long rambling code below (sorry) please let me know if you need any additional info from me.

[image: Bad image 2010]
[image: 2018]
[image]

```
"""User Defined Variables"""
year = '2009'
zipped_directory = r'/Users/Richard/NAIP'
imagery_directory = r'/Volumes/THESIS/AerialPhotos'

NatImage = 'Natural_123'  # folder name for natural color
NatStretch = 'Stretch_123' # folder for stretched natural color
FCI142 = 'Stretch_142'  # folder for false color 1
FCI423 = 'Stretch_423' # folder for false color 2
##############################################################################

import zipfile
import os
import shutil as sh
import operator
from functools import reduce
from osgeo import gdal_array
import send2trash as trash
from pathlib import Path
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

"""Define New Functions"""

# define a new function walky, similar to the walk function but more compact.
# this function has an option for max depth so when the code finishes iterating
# it doesnt go into the folders it just created and try to walk through those directories too
def walky(top, maxdepth):
    dirs, nondirs = [], []
    for name in os.listdir(top):
        (dirs if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(top, name)) else nondirs).append(name)
    yield top, dirs, nondirs
    if maxdepth > 1:
        for name in dirs:
            for x in walky(os.path.join(top, name), maxdepth - 1):
                yield x

def histogram(a, bins=list(range(0, 256))):
    fa = a.flat
    n = gdal_array.numpy.searchsorted(gdal_array.numpy.sort(fa), bins)
    n = gdal_array.numpy.concatenate([n, [len(fa)]])
    hist = n[1:]-n[:-1]
    return hist

def stretch(a):
    hist = histogram(a)
    lut = []
    for b in range(0, len(hist), 256):
     # step size
        step = reduce(operator.add, hist[b:b+256]) / 255
     # create equalization look-up table
    n = 0
    for i in range(256):
        lut.append(n / step)
        n = n + hist[i+b]
    gdal_array.numpy.take(lut, a, out=a)
    return a


"""Set up environments"""

os.chdir('/Users/Richard')

og_dir = zipped_directory + '/' + year  # directory where zip files are stored

# Create new directories
os.makedirs(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP/OG') #storage for unzipped OG images
os.makedirs(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP/OG/META')  # storage for NAIP images/Metadata
os.makedirs(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP/' + NatImage)
os.makedirs(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP/' + NatStretch)
os.makedirs(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP/' + FCI142)
os.makedirs(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP/' + FCI423)

# create path objects
rp = Path(og_dir)  # root path
rpZ = Path(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP/OG')  # location of unzipped files
df = Path(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP')  # Landing location
dpN = df / Path('OG')
dpM = df / Path('OG/META')
Nat = df / Path(NatImage)
NatSt = df / Path(NatStretch)
FCI_s142 = df / Path(FCI142)
FCI_s423 = df / Path(FCI423)

dpN = Path(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP/OG')  # location tif files will be deposited
dpM = Path(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP/OG/META')  # location meta data files will be deopsited
Nat = Path(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP') / Path(NatImage)
FCI = Path(imagery_directory + '/' + year + '/NAIP') / Path(FCI142)

"""Extract files from zip and save them in the OG Folder"""
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in walky(rp, maxdepth=1):
    for z in filenames:
        if z.endswith('.ZIP'):  # only will attempt to extract from zip files
            zippy = zipfile.ZipFile(og_dir + '/' + z)
            zippy.extractall(rpZ)
            zippy.close()

if len(os.listdir(rpZ)) == 0:
    raise IOError('unzipping unsuccessful')
else:
    print('files successfully unzipped')

"""Copy meta data from OG folder to Meta subfolder"""
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in walky(rpZ, 1):
    for f in filenames:
        if f.endswith('.txt'):
            sourcePath = Path(folderName) / f
            newPath = dpM / f
            sh.move(sourcePath, newPath)
            #trash.send2trash(f)

if len(os.listdir(dpM)) == 0:
    raise IOError('No files moved ')
else:
    print('Files successfully moved')

"""Create Natural Color images (4 band images)"""

# Get the GeoTiff driver to create an output raster
gdal.AllRegister()
gtiff_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
mem_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM')

dpNS = str(dpN)
os.chdir(dpNS)

for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(dpNS):
    for d in filenames:
        if d.endswith('.tif'):
            # open the file and it's bands
            ds = gdal.Open(d)
            if ds is None:
                raise IOError('Cound not open raster ' + d)
            r = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
            if r is None:
                raise IOError('Could not open band 1')
            g = ds.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()
            if g is None:
                raise IOError('Could not open band 2')
            b = ds.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray()
            if b is None:
                raise IOError('Could not open band 3')
            nir = ds.GetRasterBand(4).ReadAsArray()
            if nir is None:
                raise IOError('Could not open band 4')

            print('bands opened')

            """create Natural Color Image"""
            natDest = str(Nat)  # new image location
            newNatName = NatImage + '_' + d # new image name
            newNatPath = natDest + '/' + newNatName

            # create empty tiff file
            NewNat = gtiff_driver.Create(newNatPath, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, 3, gdal.GDT_Byte)
            if NewNat is None:
                raise IOError('Could not create raster ' + d)

            NewNat.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
            NewNat.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())

            print('created empty raster')

            t1_band1 = NewNat.GetRasterBand(1)
            t1_band1.WriteArray(r)
            print('band 1 written')

            t1_band2 = NewNat.GetRasterBand(2)
            t1_band2.WriteArray(g)
            print('band 2 written')

            t1_band3 = NewNat.GetRasterBand(3)
            t1_band3.WriteArray(b)
            print('band 3 written')

            NewNat = None

            print('Nat color created')

            """Create Natural Color Stretched Image"""
            arr = gdal_array.LoadFile(newNatPath)
            arr = stretch(arr)
            new_fn = str(NatSt) + '/123str_' + d # maybe update
            output = gdal_array.SaveArray(arr, new_fn, format = 'GTiff', prototype = d)
            output = None
            print('stretch created')

            del t1_band1, t1_band2, t1_band3, NewNat

            # """Create 142 Stretched Image"""
            # FCI142_r = mem_driver.Create('', ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, gdal.GDT_Byte)
            # FCI142_r.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
            # FCI142_r.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
            #
            # data_142 = np.stack((r, nir, g))
            # arr1 = stretch(data_142)
            # fn_142 = str(FCI_s142) + '/142Str_' + d
            # output = gdal_array.SaveArray(arr1, fn_142, format= 'GTiff', prototype=d)
            # output = None
            #
            # """Create 423 Stretched Image"""
            # FCI423_r = mem_driver.Create('', ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, gdal.GDT_Byte)
            # FCI423_r.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
            # FCI423_r.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
            #
            # data_423 = np.stack((nir, g, b))
            # arr1 = stretch(data_423)
            # fn_423 = str(FCI_s423) + '/423Str_' + d
            # output = gdal_array.SaveArray(arr1, fn_423, format='GTiff', prototype=d)
            # output = None

            del ds
```

Here is the readout from `gdalinfo`

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /Users/Richard/m_3311525_ne_11_1_20100428.tif
Size is 6479, 7598
Coordinate System is:
BOUNDCRS[
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["NAD83 / UTM zone 11N",
            BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
                DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
                    ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",4269]],
            CONVERSION["UTM zone 11N",
                METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                    ID["EPSG",9807]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-117,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8805]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["(E)",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["(N)",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            USAGE[
                SCOPE["unknown"],
                AREA["North America - 120°W to 114°W and NAD83 by country"],
                BBOX[30.88,-120,83.5,-114]],
            ID["EPSG",26911]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            USAGE[
                SCOPE["unknown"],
                AREA["World"],
                BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation to WGS84",
        METHOD["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)",
            ID["EPSG",9606]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8605]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8606]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8607]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8608]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8609]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8610]],
        PARAMETER["Scale difference",1,
            ID["EPSG",8611]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (598248.000000000000000,3721448.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2011:12:27 12:02:29
  TIFFTAG_DOCUMENTNAME=MORTMAR NE 3311525
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=USDA-FSA-APFO National Agriculture Image Program
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=72
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=72
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  598248.000, 3721448.000) (115d56'26.61"W, 33d37'41.92"N)
Lower Left  (  598248.000, 3713850.000) (115d56'29.62"W, 33d33'35.25"N)
Upper Right (  604727.000, 3721448.000) (115d52'15.17"W, 33d37'39.69"N)
Lower Right (  604727.000, 3713850.000) (115d52'18.39"W, 33d33'33.03"N)
Center      (  601487.500, 3717649.000) (115d54'22.45"W, 33d35'37.49"N)
Band 1 Block=6479x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=6479x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=6479x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
Band 4 Block=6479x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

Comment: Closest match on Stack seems to be https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332327/reading-big-raster-getting-warnings-using-gdal-python, but that's for silencing the warning when you're confident there's no problem, which is not the case here. Offsite the closest match I found is https://forum.sentinel-hub.com/t/geotiff-files-from-wms-server-have-errors/4352, also unresolved.

Answer (score 6):

Check what gdalinfo says about the image. Notice that you did not get an error but just a warning and it says `Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel`.

The warning means that the image has, for example, 4 samples for each pixel but the Protometric TIFF tag is set to RGB and there is no ExtraSamples tag set . GDAL gives a warning because 3 + 0 does not make 4. Then it sets one band to ExtraSample and now 3 + 1 makes 4 and everthing is OK at least technically.

**EDIT**

Gdalinto does not show the tiff tags but you need to use tiffinfo from the libtiff tools http://libtiff.org/tools.html

Here is an example from a normal RGB image:

```
tiffinfo test.tif
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Image Width: 10000 Image Length: 10000
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Sample Format: unsigned integer
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Samples/Pixel: 3
  Rows/Strip: 1
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
```

Comment: I added the readout from `gdalinfo` to my original post. I have had no issue processing 4-band images using the above code before so I don't understand why I am getting this warning now and why it is affecting the output negatively. I understand that it is just a _warning_ and not a _error_ but something is affecting the final image

Answer (score -3):

As found on Google: "RGB refers to the primary colors of light, Red, Green and Blue, that are used in monitors, television screens, digital cameras and scanners. CMYK refers to the primary colors of pigment: Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, and Black. ... You may notice a shift in color when converting from RGB to CMYK."

This is why your images got your colour changed: because it shifts from 4 channels CMYK to 3 channels RGB.

Comment: Sorry Daniel but that doesn't apply here. GIS and Remote Sensing don't use the CMYK model. When present the 4th band is usually Near-Infrared or alpha transparency. Landsat 8 for example has 11 bands ([ref](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-are-band-designations-landsat-satellites)), none of which are about pigment.