# Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples

Tags: qgis, python, raster, multi-band, band

I run a PYQGIS script to calculate `mean` and `stdev` of an area for one specific raster-band.

```
processing.run('native:zonalstatisticsfb',{ 'COLUMN_PREFIX' : '_', 'INPUT' : '/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_TSX/SHP/windows_11px.shp', 'INPUT_RASTER' : '/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_TSX/DATA/dB/09K0153_20211005T063659_TDX_db.tif', 'OUTPUT' : '/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/output.shp', 'RASTER_BAND' : 1, 'STATISTICS' : [2,4] })
```

If my raster file has `1 raster-band` then everything is fine. As you can see below things get tricky while my file has `4 raster-bands`.

> Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color
> channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining
> non-color channels as ExtraSamples.

However, I found this [topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350084/warning1-tiffreaddirectorysum-of-photometric-type-related-color-channels) but it does not help me to make this warning go away. Is there a way to define manually the *non-color channels as ExtraSamples* ?