# Suppress warnings in Python/OGR

Tags: python, ogr

I have a process in Python using OGR via the API and the command line. I am tired of my logs being filled with various warnings (so many that it no longer prints after the first 1000). These happen in Python when I call ogr2ogr *and* when I use OGR's layer.SetFeature. I expect these warnings each time,  they do not actually interfere with anything, and I do not need to see them in my logs.

I can't find anything in the documentation or online for how to suppress these warnings when they occur from an ogr2ogr call and/or with the OGR API in Python. The closest [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332327/reading-big-raster-getting-warnings-using-gdal-python/332330#332330) I found applied to GDAL, not OGR.

UPDATE: I am getting two different types of warnings that are clogging up my logs:

```
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'Shape_Length' to 'Shape_Leng'

Warning 1: Value 3.40282346638999984e+23 of field can_open of feature 0 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger number with respect to field width
```

The former only occurs once and is not much of a problem, the second one occurs for each feature in my feature class where that value is in the cell, which can be thousands of features * up to 20 columns (of course it stops printing after 1000 warnings issued). These warnings don't actually cause problems in my output and I would like to hide them.

Here is the sample code for the ogr2ogr command (I am just clipping an input gdb to an extent) that is causing these error messages, but the same also occurs when working in the OGR API, with shapefiles that have these values.

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc -102.38428516 54.5384116051 -102.031403056 54.7529375968 -spat -102.38428516 54.5384116051 -102.031403056 54.7529375968 -f "ESRI Shapefile" <output.shp> <input.gdb>
```

Comment: I could provide code for you to test however I don't know how to get you the feature class I am working with. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: @user2856 i updated the question

Comment: one option could be to tackle each of the warnings one by one until no warnings are produced? For your first warning, you could use `-lco LAUNDER=YES` or even pass the `-sql` flag to exclude the `Shape_Length` field. For the second warning, you could avoid long numerical values with `-lco PRECISION=NO`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you set the [`CPL_LOG` environment variable](https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html), you can direct the GDAL/OGR errors to a file.  If you specify the file as `/dev/null` on Linux/Mac and `NUL` on Windows then they will be suppressed completely.

i.e.

Linux

```
$ ogr2ogr  -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp test.gpkg test
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'verylongfieldname' to 'verylongfi'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'anotherlongfieldname' to 'anotherlon'
Warning 1: Value 3.40282299999999979e+23 of field anotherlon of feature 0 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger number with respect to field width
$ export CPL_LOG=/dev/null
ogr2ogr  -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp test.gpkg test
$
```

Windows

```
> ogr2ogr  -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp test.gpkg test
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'verylongfieldname' to 'verylongfi'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'anotherlongfieldname' to 'anotherlon'
Warning 1: Value 3.40282299999999979e+23 of field anotherlon of feature 0 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger number with respect to field width
> set CPL_LOG=NUL
ogr2ogr  -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp test.gpkg test
>
```

*Note the following is untested:*

The python API should respect this environment variable, but you could also try [`gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_LOG', '/dev/null')`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#SetConfigOption) (replace `'/dev/null'` with `'NUL'` on Windows).

Comment: Thanks for this. A couple of questions, if you know... Should I be setting this in my python script or just doing so on the command line/in my .bashrc file? Will this also prevent actual errors from being logged, or just warnings? I'll give it a shot...thanks

Comment: It'll prevent errors being logged, but that's not an issue for python scripts,use `gdal.UseExceptions()` and `ogr.UseExceptions()`

Comment: @user2856 Is there a way to make this work in a Jupyter Notebook? `ogr2ogr  -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp test.gpkg test`  with `! set CPL_LOG=NUL` does not work, nor does `! gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_LOG', '/dev/NUL') ` (I want to receive other warnings in Notebook, just not these :) )

Comment: It's `'NUL'` not `'/dev/NUL'` on Windows. Other than that I don't know, I don't use jupyter notebooks, but if I did (or in py scripts), I'd be using `gdal.VectorTranslate('test.shp', 'test.gpkg', layers=['test'])` not an external process.  This should work with `gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_LOG', 'NUL')` .

Answer (score 1):

When coding Python, if you want to return information about the tif image filename without no warning message printing out, so you can code as follows :

**os.system('gdalinfo -json image.tif --config CPL_LOG image.log')**

where *image.tif* is the tiled image filename and *image.log* the log filename.

It works for me with no warning messages printing out ! It also works with *gdal_translate* command adding the *--config CPL_LOG* option inside the system command line call as follows :

**os.system('gdal_translate -a_nodata None -a_srs epsg:2154 src_path_to_img target_path_to_img --config CPL_LOG path/to/logfile')**