# Suppressing GDAL/Python logging

Tags: gdal, gdal-python-binding

I'm using GDAL to clip lots (>100k) of small files from a large one with:

```
      translate = 'gdal_translate -epo -eco -ot Byte -b 1 -co NUM_THREADS=6 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co ZLEVEL=9 -projwin %s %s %s %s %s %s' %(ULmapx, ULmapy, LRmapx, LRmapy, MaskName, outmask)
      #print(translate)
      os.system(translate)
```

I've got it debugged and it works fine.  But I get the GDAL logs in the console (I'm using Spyder) and it swamps out other useful print messages from the main code.  How can I suppress the non-error console messages from GDAL?

Comment: Try `_=os.system(translate)`

Comment: Hmm, the subprocess option can't find the gdal command on the system. Odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) with  `capture_output=True`

```
import subprocess

translate = ['gdal_translate',
    '-epo', '-eco', '-ot', 'Byte', '-b', '1',
    '-co', 'NUM_THREADS=6', '-co', 'COMPRESS=DEFLATE', '-co', 'PREDICTOR=2', '-co', 'ZLEVEL=9',
    '-projwin', str(ULmapx), str(ULmapy), str(LRmapx), str(LRmapy), MaskName, outmask]

subprocess.run(translate, capture_output=True, check=True)
```

Or don't use an external process at all and use GDAL Python API directly, and tell GDAL to be quiet by [setting the CPL_LOG config option](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358593/2856):

```
from osgeo import gdal

# gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_LOG', 'NUL')  # Windows
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_LOG', '/dev/null')  # Linux/MacOS

translate = [
    '-epo', '-eco', '-ot', 'Byte', '-b', '1',
    '-co', 'NUM_THREADS=6', '-co', 'COMPRESS=DEFLATE', '-co', 'PREDICTOR=2', '-co', 'ZLEVEL=9',
    '-projwin', str(ULmapx), str(ULmapy), str(LRmapx), str(LRmapy)]

gdal.Translate(outmask, MaskName, options=translate)
```